# How to fill an array with data from axios request in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am retrieving data with axios from an API and I am trying to save the data in a variable that is an array in the component's state, but when I do I get the error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I tried looking online and converting the object to an array but with no luck so far. Here is how my effort looks like:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Post extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
      }

      state = {
        posts: []
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        const fetchPosts = async () => {
            const res = await axios.get('https://database/');
            this.setState({posts: res.data})
          };
          fetchPosts();
        }


    render() {
        const path = this.props.location.pathname;
        const postId = path.split("/").slice(-1)[0]

        return(
            <div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Post;
```

What is the right way of saving the response that I get with axios in the posts array in the component state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things wrong with your code.

1. In a class component, you don't need useState or useEffect they are the alternatives for using state in a functional component.
2. In the SetState, you would want to copy the contents of the state using a spread operator before setting your values. `this.setState({...this.state, post: res.data})`
3. Since your state is an array of Objects you will need to map over each collection using the map function.

.

```
<div>
 {this.state.posts.map(postItem => (
  <div key={postItem.id}>
    <h1>{postItem.title}</h1>
  </div>
 )}
</div>
```

For the data, do a `console.log(res)` before setState to see if it returns anything

Comment: Now when I use a spread operator the posts array gets populated successfully and it works!

Comment: Awesome, I am happy it helped. The problem was probably maybe setState() was called before your data was loaded. You can also check the response status before calling setState or use try catch.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to render item by item `mapping` the array. I will show you how with a basic example.

Instead:

```
<div>
  {this.state.posts}
</div>
```

Do:

```
<ul>
  {this.state.posts.map(post => (
     <li key={post.id}>{post.title}</li> // id required for list *
  )
)}
</ul>
```

*: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: Thanks, I can do that, but the problem is that my posts array does not recieve the response and that is my issue